# How to send some data from dynamic form using jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to send data from dynamicly generated cheboxes(when ticked) to my php script, and then to mysql data base. I've got something like that:

---

```
form method="post" id="form">
<input type="checkbox" id="1" name="tick">
<input type="checkbox" id="2" name="tick">
<input type="checkbox" id="3" name="tick">
<input type="checkbox" id="4" name="tick">
<input type="checkbox" id="5" name="tick">
<input type="checkbox" id="6" name="tick">
</form>
```

(amount of checkboxes is not const!)

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("form#form").check(function() {
  var achieved = $('input[check]');
  var id = $('input[id]');

  var data = 'achieved=' + achieved.val() + '&amp;id=' + id.val();

  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "change.php",
   data: data,
   success: function(){
    $('div.changed').fadeIn(400);
    setTimeout(function(){ $("div.changed").fadeOut(400) }, 4000);
   }

  });
  return false;
 });
});
```

---

What did I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to give your checkbox elements values (`value="something"`) you can check for on the server side.

You can also use the [`serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) method to create the parameters string instead of doing it manually.

The way you are doing it now is sure to not work because your `achieved` variable will not match any of your elements (did you mean `:checkbox`?) and `id` will match all, so the `val()` will only return the first `value`, which is not set in your example.

Also, don't use `&amp;` when you mean `&`. The encoded entity only makes sense in HTML.

I'm also sure there is no `check()` method in jQuery. Are you using a plugin ?